# IndexError: Layer [4] not found

Tags: python, linux, scapy

Im using scapy for python in linux and I wrote a code that worked on a specific pcap file, but when I tried another pcap files it showed me the eror:
IndexError: Layer [4] not found.
I tried to find a solution for this on the web, but nothing worked.

```
from scapy.all import * 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Dest_IP', 'Source_IP', 'Source_Port'])
packets = rdpcap("attack.pcap")
i = 0
for packet in packets:
    print i
    print packet[i].summary()
    if(packet[i].haslayer(IP)):
        insert_ip_dest = packet[IP].dst
        insert_ip_source = packet[IP].src
    else:
        insert_ip_dest = 'N/A'
        insert_ip_source = 'N/A'
    if(packet[i].haslayer(TCP)):
        insert_dest_port = packet[TCP].dport
    else:
        insert_dest_port = 'N/A'
    df.loc[i] = [insert_ip_dest, insert_ip_source, insert_dest_port]
    i = i+1
df.to_csv("packets.csv")
```

I even tried to use the haslayer() function but it didnt help either.
I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: please paste the full stacktrace of the error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_table.py", line 9, in <module>
    print packet[i].summary()
  File "/home/oded/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 817, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [4] not found
@dnit13

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `packet[i]`. You should change every `packet[i]` with `packet`. In scapy every packet is made by stacked layers, so when you use `packet[i]` is equivalent of saying "give me the i-th stacked layer in the packed". This means that in you code the first time the loop you looking for the first layer "in the packet stack", etc.